# What is the difference between #encode and #force_encoding in ruby?

Tags: ruby, encoding

I really do not understand the difference between `#encode` and `#force_encoding` in Ruby for the `String` class.  I understand that `"kam".force_encoding("UTF-8")` will force `"kam"` to be in UTF-8 encoding, but how is `#encode(encoding)` different?

http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-encoding

Comment: Are you talking about `String#encode` or `String#encoding`? I'd guess `String#encode` but you mention both methods and link to `String#encoding`.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Difference is pretty big. `force_encoding` sets given string encoding, but does not change the string itself, i.e.  does not change it representation in memory:

```
'łał'.bytes #=> [197, 130, 97, 197, 130]
'łał'.force_encoding('ASCII').bytes #=> [197, 130, 97, 197, 130]
'łał'.force_encoding('ASCII')   #=> "\xC5\x82a\xC5\x82"
```

`encode` assumes that the current encoding is correct and tries to change the string so it reads same way in second encoding:

```
'łał'.encode('UTF-16') #=> 'łał'
'łał'.encode('UTF-16').bytes #=> [254, 255, 1, 65, 0, 97, 1, 66]
```

In short, `force_encoding` changes the way string is being read from bytes, and `encode` changes the way string is written without changing the output (if possible)

Answer (score 17):

Read this [Changing an encoding](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Encoding.html#class-Encoding-label-Changing+an+encoding)

> The associated Encoding of a String can be changed in two different ways.
>
> First, it is possible to set the [`Encoding`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Encoding.html) of a string to a new Encoding without changing the internal byte representation of the string, with `String#force_encoding`. This is how you can tell Ruby the correct encoding of a string.

Example :

```
string = "R\xC3\xA9sum\xC3\xA9"
string.encoding #=> #<Encoding:ISO-8859-1>
string.force_encoding(Encoding::UTF_8) #=> "R\u00E9sum\u00E9"
```

> Second, it is possible to *transcode* a string, i.e. translate its internal byte representation to another encoding. Its associated encoding is also set to the other encoding. See `String#encode` for the various forms of transcoding, and the [Encoding::Converter](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Encoding/Converter.html) class for additional control over the *transcoding* process.

Example :

```
string = "R\u00E9sum\u00E9"
string.encoding #=> #<Encoding:UTF-8>
string = string.encode!(Encoding::ISO_8859_1)
#=> "R\xE9sum\xE9"
string.encoding
#=> #<Encoding::ISO-8859-1>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my analogy

- **force_encoding** ==> say the same **thing** in a different **language**
- **encode** ==> interpret the same **sound** in different **language**

where

- **bytes** ==> **thing**
- **encoding** ==> **language**
- **string output** ==> **sound**

Answer (score 0):

According to [this blog post](https://tenderlovemaking.com/2020/01/13/guide-to-string-encoding-in-ruby.html): `In Ruby, strings are a combination of an array of bytes, and an encoding object` (*).

```rb
x = 'Hello World' ---> <Encoding:UTF-8>
```

> Calling force_encoding mutates the original string, where encode creates a new string with a different encoding.

force_encoding

```rb
# before force_encoding
x = 'Hello World' ---> <Encoding:UTF-8>

x.force_encoding "US-ASCII"

# after force_encoding
x ---> <Encoding:US-ASCII>
```

encode

```rb
# before encode
x = 'Hello World' ---> <Encoding:UTF-8>

y = x.encode("US-ASCII")

# after encode
x ---> <Encoding:UTF-8>
y ---> <Encoding:US-ASCII>
```

[Another awesome blog post (read "The Solution" part)](https://yehudakatz.com/2010/05/05/ruby-1-9-encodings-a-primer-and-the-solution-for-rails/) which explain the reason why `Ruby String <Bytes + Encoding>` is designed (*).