# Ruby to Python conversion stuck on the equivalent

Tags: ruby, encoding, python-3.7

I'm converting a project from Ruby to Python. There is a force_encoding method used in Ruby. I'm stuck there not able to find anything equivalent in Python.

I've tried to use the encode method but it changes the representation of the string in memory itself.

```
callback = lambda do |context, kb, k|
    yield(k.get_bytes(0, kb).force_encoding(encoding))
end
```

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21614228/what-is-the-difference-between-encode-and-force-encoding-in-ruby) a post to help you understand difference between `encoding` and `force_encoding`.

Comment: And [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47077798/python-to-ruby-conversion-stuck-on-the-equivalent) an example for help you in conversion.

Comment: Thanks, @Nifriz but I've read those posts. I'm looking for the method in Python which does not change the representation of the string in memory if there is any or any other programmatical way to implement the same.